# Performance issues on heavy loading with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sql-tuning

Basically, we have a big production issue where our sql queries takes more than 300 seconds before ending.

We are using Mysql as SQL server, and our tables are with MyISAM.

The problematic queries are basic queries between two tables, and with a sort and group by. The issue is that each table has more than 30 millions rows.

Here is a fake example of this query :

```
SELECT    
    i.id_stat as idStat,    
    SUM(srv0.duree_st) AS dureeAppelTotale,    
    _date as dateI,    
    DATE_FORMAT(srv0._date,'%d/%m') AS datekey,    
    DATE_FORMAT(_date,'%d%m%Y') AS datekeyGroup,    
    heure,    
    SUM(srv0.nombre_st) AS nbAppel 
FROM    ids_stat i   , SRV201606 srv0  
WHERE    i.id_rubrique = srv0.id_rubrique    
    AND i.id_appli = 24071    
    AND srv0._date >= '2016-06-01 00:00:00'    
    AND srv0._date <= '2016-07-01 00:00:00'  
GROUP BY    id_stat, datekeyGroup, heure  
ORDER BY _date
```

Indexes on the ids_stat table are :

```
show index from ids_stat;
+----------+------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+----------+------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| ids_stat |          0 | PRIMARY             |            1 | id_rubrique   | A         |     7435537 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| ids_stat |          1 | id_appli_index      |            1 | id_appli      | A         |       13593 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| ids_stat |          1 | date_creation_index |            1 | date_creation | A         |     2478512 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
```

on the SRV0 table, indexes are :

```
show index from SRV201606;
+-----------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name       | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-----------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| SRV201606 |          0 | PRIMARY        |            1 | _date          | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| SRV201606 |          0 | PRIMARY        |            2 | heure          | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| SRV201606 |          0 | PRIMARY        |            3 | minute         | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| SRV201606 |          0 | PRIMARY        |            4 | id_plaque      | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| SRV201606 |          0 | PRIMARY        |            5 | id_rubrique    | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| SRV201606 |          0 | PRIMARY        |            6 | id_combinaison | A         |    27472765 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| SRV201606 |          1 | id_rubrique    |            1 | id_rubrique    | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| SRV201606 |          1 | id_combinaison |            1 | id_combinaison | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
```

Also, here is an explain of the query :

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------+----------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys          | key            | key_len | ref                         | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------+----------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | ref  | PRIMARY,id_appli_index | id_appli_index | 2       | const                       |  153 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | srv0  | ref  | PRIMARY,id_rubrique    | id_rubrique    | 8       | StatVoxProdV2.i.id_rubrique |   16 | Using where                     |
```

We also read that these old join made with where were harmless as they are transcripted as an inner join by the sql engine.

Can you help us fiding ways to tune our mysql Server so it can be boosted ? Is there any configuration that could help us out ?

Many thanks

[EDIT] 
As asked in the comments, here is he version :

SELECT VERSION();

```
+------------+
| VERSION()  |
+------------+
| 5.0.45-log |
```

Server variables :

```
show Variables;
+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| Variable_name                   | Value                            |
+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| auto_increment_increment        | 1                                |
| auto_increment_offset           | 1                                |
| automatic_sp_privileges         | ON                               |
| back_log                        | 50                               |
| basedir                         | /usr/local/                      |
| binlog_cache_size               | 32768                            |
| bulk_insert_buffer_size         | 8388608                          |
| character_set_client            | utf8                             |
| character_set_connection        | utf8                             |
| character_set_database          | latin1                           |
| character_set_filesystem        | binary                           |
| character_set_results           | utf8                             |
| character_set_server            | latin1                           |
| character_set_system            | utf8                             |
| character_sets_dir              | /usr/local/share/mysql/charsets/ |
| collation_connection            | utf8_general_ci                  |
| collation_database              | latin1_swedish_ci                |
| collation_server                | latin1_swedish_ci                |
| completion_type                 | 0                                |
| concurrent_insert               | 1                                |
| connect_timeout                 | 5                                |
| datadir                         | THEDATADIR            |
| date_format                     | %Y-%m-%d                         |
| datetime_format                 | %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s                |
| default_week_format             | 0                                |
| delay_key_write                 | ON                               |
| delayed_insert_limit            | 100                              |
| delayed_insert_timeout          | 300                              |
| delayed_queue_size              | 1000                             |
| div_precision_increment         | 4                                |
| engine_condition_pushdown       | OFF                              |
| expire_logs_days                | 32                               |
| flush                           | OFF                              |
| flush_time                      | 0                                |
| ft_boolean_syntax               | + -><()~*:""&|                   |
| ft_max_word_len                 | 84                               |
| ft_min_word_len                 | 4                                |
| ft_query_expansion_limit        | 20                               |
| ft_stopword_file                | (built-in)                       |
| group_concat_max_len            | 1024                             |
| have_archive                    | NO                               |
| have_bdb                        | NO                               |
| have_blackhole_engine           | NO                               |
| have_compress                   | YES                              |
| have_crypt                      | YES                              |
| have_csv                        | NO                               |
| have_dynamic_loading            | YES                              |
| have_example_engine             | NO                               |
| have_federated_engine           | NO                               |
| have_geometry                   | YES                              |
| have_innodb                     | DISABLED                         |
| have_isam                       | NO                               |
| have_merge_engine               | YES                              |
| have_ndbcluster                 | NO                               |
| have_openssl                    | NO                               |
| have_ssl                        | NO                               |
| have_query_cache                | YES                              |
| have_raid                       | NO                               |
| have_rtree_keys                 | YES                              |
| have_symlink                    | YES                              |
| hostname                        | THEHOSTNAME                 |
| init_connect                    |                                  |
| init_file                       |                                  |
| init_slave                      |                                  |
| innodb_additional_mem_pool_size | 1048576                          |
| innodb_autoextend_increment     | 8                                |
| innodb_buffer_pool_awe_mem_mb   | 0                                |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size         | 1048576                          |
| innodb_checksums                | ON                               |
| innodb_commit_concurrency       | 0                                |
| innodb_concurrency_tickets      | 500                              |
| innodb_data_file_path           |                                  |
| innodb_data_home_dir            |                                  |
| innodb_doublewrite              | ON                               |
| innodb_fast_shutdown            | 1                                |
| innodb_file_io_threads          | 4                                |
| innodb_file_per_table           | OFF                              |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  | 1                                |
| innodb_flush_method             |                                  |
| innodb_force_recovery           | 0                                |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout        | 50                               |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  | OFF                              |
| innodb_log_arch_dir             |                                  |
| innodb_log_archive              | OFF                              |
| innodb_log_buffer_size          | 1048576                          |
| innodb_log_file_size            | 5242880                          |
| innodb_log_files_in_group       | 2                                |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir       |                                  |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct      | 90                               |
| innodb_max_purge_lag            | 0                                |
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups      | 1                                |
| innodb_open_files               | 300                              |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout      | OFF                              |
| innodb_support_xa               | ON                               |
| innodb_sync_spin_loops          | 20                               |
| innodb_table_locks              | ON                               |
| innodb_thread_concurrency       | 8                                |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay       | 10000                            |
| interactive_timeout             | 28800                            |
| join_buffer_size                | 131072                           |
| key_buffer_size                 | 402653184                        |
| key_cache_age_threshold         | 300                              |
| key_cache_block_size            | 1024                             |
| key_cache_division_limit        | 100                              |
| language                        | /usr/local/share/mysql/english/  |
| large_files_support             | ON                               |
| large_page_size                 | 0                                |
| large_pages                     | OFF                              |
| lc_time_names                   | en_US                            |
| license                         | GPL                              |
| local_infile                    | ON                               |
| locked_in_memory                | OFF                              |
| log                             | OFF                              |
| log_bin                         | ON                               |
| log_bin_trust_function_creators | OFF                              |
| log_error                       |                                  |
| log_queries_not_using_indexes   | OFF                              |
| log_slave_updates               | OFF                              |
| log_slow_queries                | ON                               |
| log_warnings                    | 1                                |
| long_query_time                 | 10                               |
| low_priority_updates            | OFF                              |
| lower_case_file_system          | OFF                              |
| lower_case_table_names          | 0                                |
| max_allowed_packet              | 1047552                          |
| max_binlog_cache_size           | 4294967295                       |
| max_binlog_size                 | 104857600                        |
| max_connect_errors              | 10                               |
| max_connections                 | 100                              |
| max_delayed_threads             | 20                               |
| max_error_count                 | 64                               |
| max_heap_table_size             | 134217728                        |
| max_insert_delayed_threads      | 20                               |
| max_join_size                   | 4294967295                       |
| max_length_for_sort_data        | 1024                             |
| max_prepared_stmt_count         | 16382                            |
| max_relay_log_size              | 0                                |
| max_seeks_for_key               | 4294967295                       |
| max_sort_length                 | 1024                             |
| max_sp_recursion_depth          | 0                                |
| max_tmp_tables                  | 32                               |
| max_user_connections            | 0                                |
| max_write_lock_count            | 4294967295                       |
| multi_range_count               | 256                              |
| myisam_data_pointer_size        | 6                                |
| myisam_max_sort_file_size       | 2147483647                       |
| myisam_recover_options          | OFF                              |
| myisam_repair_threads           | 1                                |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size         | 67108864                         |
| myisam_stats_method             | nulls_unequal                    |
| net_buffer_length               | 16384                            |
| net_read_timeout                | 30                               |
| net_retry_count                 | 10                               |
| net_write_timeout               | 60                               |
| new                             | OFF                              |
| old_passwords                   | OFF                              |
| open_files_limit                | 4096                             |
| optimizer_prune_level           | 1                                |
| optimizer_search_depth          | 62                               |
| pid_file                        | /usr2/mysql/var/run/mysqld.pid   |
| port                            | 3306                             |
| preload_buffer_size             | 32768                            |
| profiling                       | OFF                              |
| profiling_history_size          | 15                               |
| protocol_version                | 10                               |
| query_alloc_block_size          | 8192                             |
| query_cache_limit               | 1048576                          |
| query_cache_min_res_unit        | 4096                             |
| query_cache_size                | 33554432                         |
| query_cache_type                | ON                               |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate    | OFF                              |
| query_prealloc_size             | 8192                             |
| range_alloc_block_size          | 2048                             |
| read_buffer_size                | 2093056                          |
| read_only                       | OFF                              |
| read_rnd_buffer_size            | 8384512                          |
| relay_log_purge                 | ON                               |
| relay_log_space_limit           | 0                                |
| rpl_recovery_rank               | 0                                |
| secure_auth                     | OFF                              |
| secure_file_priv                |                                  |
| server_id                       | 2                                |
| skip_external_locking           | ON                               |
| skip_networking                 | OFF                              |
| skip_show_database              | OFF                              |
| slave_compressed_protocol       | OFF                              |
| slave_load_tmpdir               | /usr2/mysql/tmp/                 |
| slave_net_timeout               | 3600                             |
| slave_skip_errors               | ALL                              |
| slave_transaction_retries       | 10                               |
| slow_launch_time                | 2                                |
| socket                          | /usr2/mysql/var/run/mysqld.sock  |
| sort_buffer_size                | 2097144                          |
| sql_big_selects                 | ON                               |
| sql_mode                        |                                  |
| sql_notes                       | ON                               |
| sql_warnings                    | OFF                              |
| ssl_ca                          |                                  |
| ssl_capath                      |                                  |
| ssl_cert                        |                                  |
| ssl_cipher                      |                                  |
| ssl_key                         |                                  |
| storage_engine                  | MyISAM                           |
| sync_binlog                     | 0                                |
| sync_frm                        | ON                               |
| system_time_zone                | CET                              |
| table_cache                     | 512                              |
| table_lock_wait_timeout         | 50                               |
| table_type                      | MyISAM                           |
| thread_cache_size               | 8                                |
| thread_stack                    | 196608                           |
| time_format                     | %H:%i:%s                         |
| time_zone                       | SYSTEM                           |
| timed_mutexes                   | OFF                              |
| tmp_table_size                  | 134217728                        |
| tmpdir                          | /usr2/mysql/tmp/                 |
| transaction_alloc_block_size    | 8192                             |
| transaction_prealloc_size       | 4096                             |
| tx_isolation                    | REPEATABLE-READ                  |
| updatable_views_with_limit      | YES                              |
| version                         | 5.0.45-log                       |
| version_comment                 | Source distribution              |
| version_compile_machine         | i686                             |
| version_compile_os              | pc-linux-gnu                     |
| wait_timeout                    | 28800                            |
```

ids_stat schema :

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE ids_stat;
CREATE TABLE `ids_stat` (
  `id_rubrique` bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  `id_stat` int(10) default NULL,
  `id_appli` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `nom_rubrique` varchar(240) NOT NULL,
  `date_creation` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id_rubrique`),
  KEY `id_appli_index` (`id_appli`),
  KEY `date_creation_index` (`date_creation`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And the SRV0 example schema :

```
CREATE TABLE `SRV201606` (
  `id_rubrique` bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  `id_plaque` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `id_combinaison` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `_date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `heure` tinyint(3) NOT NULL default '0',
  `minute` tinyint(3) NOT NULL default '0',
  `nombre_entree` mediumint(8) unsigned default '0',
  `nombre_st` mediumint(8) unsigned default NULL,
  `duree_st` mediumint(8) unsigned default NULL,
  `flag` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`_date`,`heure`,`minute`,`id_plaque`,`id_rubrique`,`id_combinaison`),
  KEY `id_rubrique` (`id_rubrique`),
  KEY `id_combinaison` (`id_combinaison`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: First of all, you need to jump on fixing those joins, they're the old outdated style, see here for further reading; https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: You should give some info about indexes on the tables in the query.

Comment: First, as @RichBenner sad, try to use `INNER JOIN` on this: `WHERE    i.id_rubrique = srv0.id_rubrique`.Second, you need to index your tables. Add index to `_date`, `id_stat, datekeyGroup, heure ` and all of your fields after `SELECT`. You can add an `EXPLAIN` befor select, see, what happens.

Comment: Please let us see a little bit more to find out what the server really doing Please post the output from : SELECT VERSION(); show Variables; SHOW CREATE TABLE ids_stat; and SHOW CREATE TABLE SRV0; then i will give you a answer with a much better perfomace

Comment: Question updated regarding your comments.

Comment: @user1996772 - sorry there no field **id**  in the table **ids_stat** what you reference in your query. can you please fix it in the answer ?

Comment: Your _date field is just a date, so no need to check the date and time for it. I am wondering if MySQL is trying to do a data conversion on _date, hence ignoring any index on that. With _date being checked as a date then it might have the option of reversing the order it joins in (as I suspect _date limit the returned rows quite well).

Comment: After having checked all the different options, it seems that the performance issue is mostly caused by the version of Mysql, and the hardware performance of the machine.

Therefore, the answer from Bernd Buffen is the best one, and allows us to have better performance, bu we have to increade the machine hardware before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not my finished Answer!,

but can you only run this query on your big tables and give me the execution time and the EXPLAIN of it.

ALTER TABLE SRV201606 ADD KEY idx_rubrique_date (`_date`,`id_rubrique`);

```
SELECT
    i.*,    
    SUM(srv0.duree_st) AS dureeAppelTotale,    
    srv0._date AS dateI,    
    DATE_FORMAT(srv0._date,'%d/%m') AS datekey,    
    DATE_FORMAT(_date,'%d%m%Y') AS datekeyGroup,    
    heure,    
    SUM(srv0.nombre_st) AS nbAppel 
FROM (
  SELECT    
        id_rubrique
        , id_stat
  FROM    ids_stat
  WHERE    
    id_appli = 24071    
  GROUP BY    id_stat
) AS i
LEFT JOIN SRV201606 srv0 ON i.id_rubrique = srv0.id_rubrique
WHERE
  srv0._date >= '2016-06-01'    
AND 
  srv0._date <= '2016-07-01' 
GROUP BY    id_stat, _date, heure  
ORDER BY _date;
```

Comment: This query takes 17.29 sec to run. Here is the explain :http://pastebin.com/qHDwsUmN

Also, this query gives me less result than the original one.

Comment: Is the result ok ?

Comment: @user1996772 - can you please test again and also post time and explain. i have add a index in my answer and change the query.

Comment: Hello, with the index, it's faster, rather less than 7 sec, but it does not give me all the informations i had before, mainly because the GROUP BY id_stat is retrieving less informations from the ids_stat table :( and without this group by, well... it takes the same amount of time as the previous query. Here is the explain : http://pastebin.com/dYZdDztR

Comment: sorry, first your MySQL Version is now **9 Years OLD**. It time to update. you can also use MariaDB 10.1.xx. There are many many bugs resolved. can you show me are result of your and my query to see what are the difference. I also have updated my answer in th GROUP BY condition. it is faster to use _date

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding _date to

```
CREATE TABLE `SRV201606` (
...

KEY `id_rubrique` (`id_rubrique`),
```

so

```
KEY `id_rubrique` (`_date`,`id_rubrique`),
```

or alternatively

```
KEY `date-id_rubrique` (`_date`,`id_rubrique`),
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the times from the dates and post the EXPLAIN, something like this:-

```
SELECT    
    i.id_stat as idStat,    
    SUM(srv0.duree_st) AS dureeAppelTotale,    
    _date as dateI,    
    DATE_FORMAT(srv0._date,'%d/%m') AS datekey,    
    DATE_FORMAT(_date,'%d%m%Y') AS datekeyGroup,    
    heure,    
    SUM(srv0.nombre_st) AS nbAppel 
FROM    ids_stat i
INNER JOIN SRV201606 srv0  
ON    i.id_rubrique = srv0.id_rubrique    
WHERE i.id_appli = 24071    
AND srv0._date BETWEEN '2016-06-01' AND '2016-07-01'  
GROUP BY    id_stat, 
            datekeyGroup, 
            heure  
ORDER BY _date
```

I suspect that MySQL is trying to do a date conversion to a date / time for each row returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE i.id_rubrique = srv0.id_rubrique    
  AND i.id_appli = 24071    
  AND srv0._date >= '2016-06-01 00:00:00'    
  AND srv0._date <= '2016-07-01 00:00:00'
```

Did you want both midnights?  Suggest doing this instead:

```
  AND srv0._date >= '2016-06-01'    
  AND srv0._date  < '2016-06-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Need these indexes to facilitate starting with `i`:

```
i: (id_appli, id_rubrique, id_stat)  -- in this order; and is 'covering'
srv0:  (id_rubrique, _date)          -- '=' part first, then 'range'
```

Need these indexes to facilitate starting with `srv0`:

```
i: (id_rubrique, id_appli, id_stat)  -- in this order; and is 'covering'
srv0:  (_date)                       -- adding anything after `_date` is useless
```

Adding all those indexes will give the optimizer the option to start with either table and do it efficiently.